# How to add a new time zone to Windows Registry Hive?

Tags: sql-server, windows, timezone, registry

I am looking for a way to install the UTC-07 time zone in my windows registry hive so I can possibly use it in SQL Server with the `AT TIME ZONE` function.

As the documentation states ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)), `AT TIME ZONE` function supports the time zones that are installed in the windows registry.

The path is the following:
`KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`

I've done some research before asking this question but I haven't been able to find an answer to this specifically.

I am expecting a way to add a new time zone to the registry hive only if possible.

Feel free to ask for more context if needed, thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: Don't think it's possible (or at least it would just be overwritten on the next Windows update). But what's wrong with just using the `Pacific Standard Time` zone https://dbfiddle.uk/c2gZH11h

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for your response! 
The problem that I am facing is that I am working with a city who's time zone is static at UTC-07 (Hermosillo, Sonora) and I believe that if I use the Pacific Standard Time it will change with the daylight saving time in some point. 
P.D. Yes, the city of Hermosillo in Mexico has decided to stay at UTC-07 forever.

Comment: `Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)` see above fiddle

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you! Currently I am using `Mountain Standard Time` and I haven't faced any issue yet but I'm still afraid if it will change if dst changes to true (I'm not sure if SQL does that with the time zones in sys.time_zone_info). Just to give a bit more context, my query gets datetimes from openweathermap so we can schedule pole lights by taking in count the sunrise and sunset, that's why I am seeking for a safier way to convert those datetimes to UTC-07.

Comment: Well Windows gets updates for time zone information. If that time zone was agreed by governments to begin using DST then it would change, otherwise there is no reason it would. Why don't you just use UTC and adjust manually using `SWITCHOFFSET`

Comment: Actually that was the plan B or my last resort hehe, but I think that's the only way to achieve it without worries, thank you @Charlieface, I was afraid of asking this here but I am lucky that you answered it with patience :D